# Failed mysql upgrade to 5.5 on debian wheezy

Tags: mysql, debian, apt

When upgrading debian squeeze to wheezy, the upgrade of mysql to `mysql-server-5.5` fails:

```
# apt-get dist-upgrade -u
...
Setting up mysql-server-5.5 (5.5.31+dfsg-0+wheezy1) ...
[ ok ] Stopping MySQL database server: mysqld.
...
[FAIL] Starting MySQL database server: mysqld . . . . . . . . . . . . . . failed!
invoke-rc.d: initscript mysql, action "start" failed.
dpkg: error processing mysql-server-5.5 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-server:
 mysql-server depends on mysql-server-5.5; however:
  Package mysql-server-5.5 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing mysql-server (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-server-5.5
 mysql-server
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

When I run `/usr/bin/mysqld_safe --skip-syslog`, the resulting log file has this message repeated:

```
130520 23:54:23  InnoDB: Error: trying to access tablespace 1 page no. 2,
InnoDB: but the tablespace does not exist or is just being dropped.
```

As far as I know, I don't have any InnoDB tables.

What do? I don't want to `--purge` mysql unless it's absolutely necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears as if there were innoDB-related files (`ibdata1`, `ib_logfile`, etc) in my `/var/lib/mysql/` directory. Per the suggestions [in this mailing list post](http://lists.alioth.debian.org/pipermail/pkg-mysql-maint/2013-March/005606.html), I ran `rm ib*` and re-ran `apt-get dist-upgrade`. Everything appears to work.

Answer (score 0):

I had debian backports in my /etc/apt/sources.list, and I just blindly replaced words squeeze with wheezy without checking what repos I'm using. When I did dist-upgrade, I ended up with similar results that you are seeing.

Remove backports repos, if you have any, and do an update/upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem. The issue was with the source list of debian wheezy.
The following steps solved my problem for mysql-server in debian wheezy.

1. Go to http://debgen.simplylinux.ch/ to generate the source list.

2.Generate the source list.

3. Copy and paste the generated list into your /etc/apt/sources.list file. (Make a backup first!)

4.After that, run #apt-get update

Hope it helps.